# How to save password via keychanwrapper after kill process app

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication

I create app to log in I want to keep username and Password for use app next time 
but username and password not read to use it again after kill process

this is my code

ChkViewController.m (it is initial view controller)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    LoginViewController *log;
    NSString *password = [log.keychainItem objectForKey:kSecValueData];
    NSString *username = [log.keychainItem objectForKey:kSecAttrAccount];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"link"]];
    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSString *memstat = [dataDict objectForKey:@"MemberStatus"]; //1 is registered user 0 is unregistered user
    NSString *ck = memstat;
    if([memstat isEqual :@"1"]){
        MainViewController *mv = [[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Main"bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:mv animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        LoginViewController *log2 = [[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login"bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:log2 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

LoginViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender{
    NSString *msg;
    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:hello message:name delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    if([_user isEqual:@""]||[_pass isEqual:@""] ){
        msg = @"please fill username or password";
        [alert show];
    }
    else{
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"link"]];
        id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSString *memstat = [dataDict objectForKey:@"MemberStatus"]; //1 is registered user 0 is unregistered user
        NSString *ck = memstat;
        if([ck isEqual:@"0"]){
            msg =@"Username or password is incorrect";
            [alert show];
        }
    _keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"MyApp" accessGroup:nil];
    [keychainItem setObject:_pass forKey:kSecValueData];
    [keychainItem setObject:_user forKey:kSecAttrAccount];
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add this line in your app `[wrapper setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible];`

Comment: I used it but it have still.

Comment: now I solved my problems by myself